# Is there any sort of universal coordinate system?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, universe

Is it possible to pinpoint the location of the earth in a universal coordinate system of the universe? Maybe the CMB could be used somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a universal rest frame of reference?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20015/is-there-a-universal-rest-frame-of-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a postulate of special relativity that no reference frame/coordinate system has preference over any other.  Measurements in one reference frame are just as valid as those in another, even when they give different results.  As for how "here" is defined, it depends entirely on the chosen reference frame/coordinate system -- there is no single objective answer.  The closest we can come to a universal reference frame is to look at spacetime as a 4D geometry (with time as the 4th dimension) and then we can define what are called [spacetime intervals](https://phys.libretexts.org/Courses/Skidmore_College/Introduction_to_General_Relativity/01%3A_Special_Relativity/1.02%3A_The_Spacetime_Interval), which are reference frame independent.

Edit:
It's not so much that we *can't* have a universal reference frame, so much as that SR has made it *unnecessary.*  That is, postulating the existence of a universal reference frame, in addition to all the other relative reference frames, would just give us an extra mathematical object that doesn't help in explaining anything.  Interestingly though, prior to the development of SR by Einstein, physicists did think there was some sort of universal reference which they called "luminiferous aether". PBS Spacetime did a video about it a while ago, explaining how the Michelson-Moorely experiment, which was expected to verify the existence of the aether, failed to do so and how special relativity explains the actual experimental results.  I found it quite interesting and it might give you some insight into why we don't need a universal reference frame: [PBS Spacetime: How the Luminiferous Aether Led to Special Relativity](https://youtu.be/M3GQM7tuq2w)

Comment: To be clear, I'm not looking for a single answer, I'm looking for any answer at all (which could be translated to other coordinates). Like say you disappeared and wanted to reappear in the same spot a day later, how would you find it without a trajectory? Like how could you choose any point in the universe at all to begin with? If you are saying it's not possible, ok. And even if so, it sounds like calculated projection of movement of objects in space would need to be taken into account, somehow, if the 3D coordinate system was found.

Comment: @user14094230, First, see my answer edit.  Second, what I'm saying is that you can't _define_ a trajectory at all without first choosing a coordinate to work in.  To oversimplify, that essentially means choosing some object in spacetime to be at rest relative to everything else. For most practical purposes, we choose that to be the earth, since it tends to make the calculations simplest when what we care about is the movement of objects on the surface of the earth. On the other hand, if we're talking about the motion of planets in the solar system, we usually choose the sun to be at rest, etc.

Comment: As for how to choose that point, like I said, usually we just choose whatever makes the relevant calculations the simplest, but really we could choose any point we want.  e.g. If we really wanted to, we could use a coordinate system where the sun and planets orbit the earth and that would be entirely consistent with the laws of physics and mathematics.  We usually _don't_ do that only because it would make the calculations of orbits _way_ more complicated and harder to explain.

Comment: Maybe I should delete my question. It might be too much sci-fi nonsense. I'm saying if you suddenly appear in the universe (after time travel or teleportation without a trajectory), if you used the earth as a coordinate system, how would you know where the earth is? Like is there an overall universal structure you could use to pinpoint locations?

Comment: @user14094230, as I said, no, there's no universal reference frame.  As for suddenly appearing somewhere, without having traveled through space to get there (which I assume is what you mean by "without a trajectory"), yeah that's purely sci-fi/fantasy.  And while I'm sure it's possible to come up with mathematical models of various fictional universes that allow for such teleportation, that's outside the scope of this site. If what you actually want to know is what such a model might look like and if it would include a universal reference frame, you could perhaps try posting on the math SE.

Comment: And no, you don't need to delete the question, as it may still be useful to other people.

Comment: @user14094230 Re, "if you used the earth as a coordinate system, how would you know where the earth is?" That's easy. In a coordinate system that is rigidly attached to the Earth, the Earth _does not move._ By definition! You always find the Earth in exactly the same place. Maybe "use the Earth as a coordinate system" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I think my question wasn't clear enough. If earth is always in the same place, how is the same place located in the universe in general? It works both ways, if you can pinpoint a spot, then you can use that spot as your base coordinate, but you need it both ways.

Comment: @user14094230, that's the thing -- you _can't_ have it both ways.  Position is an _inherently_ relative property -- you can _only_ define an object's position relative to some reference frame.  There _is no_ "in general" position for an object in space -- only its position relative to a given coordinate system.  That's the thing you've really gotta get through your head -- there IS NO universal reference frame, no "in general" or absolute position or speed.